# Problema en java (The method getNombre() is undefined for the type String)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, java-ee

Estoy programando una simulación de un mercado con eclipse en Java con archivos JSP. Mi problema viene en que me dice que `getNombre()` no está definido para *String*, cuando si lo está. Adjunto los respectivos códigos:

**Producto.java**

```
package models;

public class Producto {

String nombre;
String descripcion;
double precio;

public Producto(String nombre, String descripcion, double precio) 
{
    super();
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.precio = precio;
}

public Producto() {
    super();
}

public Producto(String nombre, double precio) {
    super();
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.precio = precio;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public double getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}
```

En producto se puede ver que todo está correcto, al menos, yo lo veo bien. No sé que es lo que puede fallar, ya que está todo en *public* para poder usarlo también en *ProductoDAO*.

En este código es donde me da el error:

> The method getNombre() is undefined for the type String

**ProductoDAO.java**

```
package modeloDAO;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import config.Conexion;
import interfaces.CRUD;
import models.Producto;

public class ProductoDAO implements CRUD{
    Conexion cn = new Conexion();
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    Producto p = new Producto();

    @Override
    public List<Producto> listar() {
        ArrayList<Producto>list = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM producto";
        try {
            con = cn.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                Producto p = new Producto();
                p.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
                p.setDescripcion(rs.getString("descripcion"));
                p.setPrecio(rs.getInt("precio"));
                
                list.add(p);
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Producto list(String nombre) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Producto pro) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO producto(nombre, descripcion, precio) VALUES"
                + "('"p.getNombre()+"','" + p.getDescripcion() + "','" + p.getPrecio() "')";
        try {
            
            con = cn.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean edit(Producto pro) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(String nombre) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

También me da el siguiente error en los paréntesis del SQL:

> Syntax error on token ""')"", delete this token

Pero no sé que a se debe tampoco, ya que veo que todas las comillas dobles y simples están bien cerradas. Espero sus respuestas. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: El parámetro de este método: `public boolean add(Producto pro) {`  se llama **`pro`**, pero luego, en el cuerpo del método, usas un objeto `p`. Debes cambiarlo por `pro` en todos los usos dentro del método, o cambiar el nombre del parámetro a `p` en la definición del método.

Comment: Lo he intentado también, pero me sigue dando el mismo error, y me dice que pro no es un token valido y que lo elimine...

Comment: Esto no compila: `+ "('"pro.getNombre()`, debería ser: `+ "('" + pro.getNombre()`. Te falta un +

Comment: Tenías razón. Faltaba un +. Igualmente en el final también me faltaba eso. Muchas gracias de verdad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en el método `add()`.

Por un lado, en la definición del método, llamas al parámetro `pro`:

```
public boolean add(Producto pro) {
```

Pero luego, en el cuerpo del método te refieres a él como `p`, cuando debería ser `pro`, o bien cambiar el nombre del parámetro a `p`.

El otro error es un error de sintaxis en tu instrucción SQL, falta un `+` antes de `+p.getNombre()`, pero de todos modos esa consulta es insegura, deberías usar consultas preparadas **adecuadamente** para evitar *Inyección sQL*.

Tu método debería funcionar así, y sería seguro:

```
@Override
public boolean add(Producto p) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO producto(nombre, descripcion, precio) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    try {
        
        con = cn.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1,p.getNombre());
        ps.setString(2,p.getDescripcion());
        /*
           *OJO: Puede que aquí necesites otro método
           *por ejemplo, si el tipo de dato es DECIMAL
           *el método sería setBigDecimal en vez de setString
        */
        ps.setString(3,p.getPrecio());

        /*
           En las consultas de inserción ps devuelve un int
           que sería el total de filas insertadas
        */
        int row = ps.executeQuery();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        
    }
    return false;
}
```

**PD:** No me meto con la lógica de tu método en la respuesta porque no conozco el contexto, pero no tiene sentido que devuelva siempre `false` ¿? Pero eso ya es asunto tuyo.

Comment: En efecto eso era lo que me fallaba. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Tuyuyi me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos...